# Is there a library for stellar equivalent to web3js for Ethereum?

Tags: transactions, assets, token, wallets, token-wallet

I am considering creating a stellar token or asset. I have done this before with ethereum but not with stellar.

I would also like an app to be able to:

- Create a wallet for the user so that they can receive and send the tokens/asset.
- Be able to implement functionality to transfer the tokens to other wallets.
- Be able to access a transaction history for the token for that wallet.

In web3 for ethereum this is accomplished by:

- Using the create account function to create a wallet for wallet creation.
- For sending tokens, I can create a raw transaction and pass in a call to the token contract as data to transfer the token.
- For seeing token transaction history I use an API from etherscan.

I would love to know if this functionality is possible with Stellar tokens before I go down the road of trying to develop a project, and would appreciate any help or advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to write a Stellar-powered solution, start with [Stellar Development Guides](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/).

All tasks from your list are very basic and all of them are described in the documentation, so without any doubts you will be able to implement your case. Just copy-paste a few blocks of code from docs, change some constants here and there (like token name or issuing account address), and you have your proof of concept ready.

You even don't need anything like MyEtherWallet or MetaMask, users will be able to work with your app from any browser.

Answer (score 0):

The [JavaScript Stellar SDK](https://github.com/stellar/js-stellar-sdk) may be helpful to you.